# Passing a variable in .load()

Tags: jquery

I have a page with many divs named `.comment_holder` which each contain a different id number e.g.

```
<div class="comment_holder" id="123"></div>
<div class="comment_holder" id="345"></div>
```

I want to pass the id into a page which I'm loading which appends the `.comment_holder` div when an action is performed. Here's what i'm trying:

```
$('.comment_holder').load('/pages/includes/wall.php', { 
    var wlid = $(this).attr("id");
    wl_id: wlid; 
});
```

But I get: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

What should I do differently?

Comment: could you verify what object is refered to by 'this'?

Answer (score 3):

The `data` parameter is not a proper object literal.  `this` will also not be in scope within the object literal, so iterate through the elements calling the load function for each element. Use the element passed to the function to retrieve the id.

```
$('.comment_holder').each(function(index, elem){
   $(elem).load('/pages/includes/wall.php', { 
        wl_id: $(elem).attr("id") 
    });
});
```

**Similar Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qQ4Np/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clicker').click( function(){ 
var myId = $(this).attr("id");

$('.comment_holder').load('/pages/includes/wall.php', { 
    myId: myId; 
});});
```

And wall.php:

```
$myId = $_POST['myId'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to load data dynamiccaly on page load you have to do it in loop $.each()

```
$('.comment_holder').each( function(){ 
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).load('/pages/includes/wall.php', { 
        myId: myId; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you cant have var statements inside a object literal like that. so just assign the id to the object property

```
$('.comment_holder').load('/pages/includes/wall.php', { 
   wl_id: $("comment_holder").attr("id")
});
```

but that is not going to work if you have multiple elements whit the `.comment_holder` class. so i suggest using Kevin's method and looping the collection.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, `this` doesn't refer to the selected element.